# VB .Net Print Datagrid in Multiple Pages

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing, datagrid

I’m new to VB .Net and this website has helped me a lot. I want to print the data from my datagrid and it doesn’t print properly.

With this code, it will print 1 page only and prints what fits in one page. The rest that doesn’t fit first page will not be printed.

```
If gridPTrans.RowCount > 0 Then 'Datagrid is not empty
    y = y + 25 'Height
    With gridPTrans
        Do While mRow < .RowCount 'Loop datagrid
            If mRow = .RowCount - 1 Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            row = .Rows(mRow)
            drawPoint = New PointF(x, y)

            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                MessageBox.Show("Y: " & y)
                strValue = (intValue.ToString + ".  " + gridPTrans.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString())
                e.Graphics.DrawString(strValue, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint)
                intValue += 1
                MessageBox.Show(" " & strValue)
            Next
            y += 18
            mRow += 1
        Loop 
        mRow = 0
    End With 
End If 

If y > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
    e.HasMorePages = True
    MessageBox.Show("e.HasMorePages: " & e.HasMorePages)
    y = (e.MarginBounds.Top) / 2
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I tried a different code. With this code, it will print infinite pages of the first page.

```
If gridPTrans.RowCount > 0 Then 'TRANSFER is not empty
    y = y + 25
    With gridPTrans
        Do While mRow < .RowCount 'Loop datagrid
            If mRow = .RowCount - 1 Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            row = .Rows(mRow)
            drawPoint = New PointF(x, y)

            If y > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                MessageBox.Show("e.HasMorePages: " & e.HasMorePages)
                y = (e.MarginBounds.Top) / 2
                Exit Sub
            End If

            'Print datagrid
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                MessageBox.Show("Y: " & y)
                strValue = (intValue.ToString + ".  " + gridPTrans.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString())
                e.Graphics.DrawString(strValue, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint)
                intValue += 1
                MessageBox.Show(" " & strValue)
            Next
            y += 18
            mRow += 1
        Loop
        mRow = 0    
    End With 
End If
```

Comment: why are you resetting `mRow = 0`, you should probable don't require that.

Comment: I tried to remove mRow = 0 and it will print multiple pages of scenario #1.

Comment: Anybody? How do I make my code print to second page? Thanks!

Comment: Why not create a report(rdlc) and populate it with the same datasource used to populate your datagrid. Then you can control the look an feel of the printed report.